# How can I compose the content of my PyPI project description?

Tags: python, github, pypi, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I am developping a [Python project](https://github.com/AlexisBRENON/ewmh_m2m) with the following layout (setup with PyScaffold):

```
project/
 - src/
 - docs/
   - _static/
     - assets/
       - logo.svg
   - index.rst
 - README.rst
 - AUTHORS.txt
 - setup.py
 - setup.cfg
 - ...
```

This project is hosted on GitHub, published on Pypi, and documented on ReadTheDocs. I would like that these 3 sites render a similar content as main page (README, long description, index page) except for some details:

- On GitHub, links should redirect to GitHub file page
- On Pypi and Read the Docs, links should redirect to Read the Docs pages
- On branches on GitHub, links should redirect to branched files (not `master` ones)

Currently, I use a `README.rst` looking like:

```rst
.. _Authors: http://readthedocs/latest/authors.html

.. |logo| image:: http://readthedocs/assets/logo.svg
   :alt: Logo
   :width: 500


.. EndOfLinks

|logo|

`Authors`_
```

A `docs/index.rst` as follow:

```rst
.. _Authors: ./authors.html

.. |logo| image:: ./_static/ewmh_m2m.svg
   :alt: Logo
   :width: 500

.. include:: ../README.rst
   :start-after: EndOfLinks
```

And a `setup.cfg`:

```cfg
long-description = file: README.rst
long-description-content-type = text/x-rst; charset=UTF-8
```

However, on new branches, the README rendering or links do not reflect any changes in the underlying files, like in [this example](https://github.com/AlexisBRENON/ewmh_m2m/tree/test_logo_inclusion).

Using relative links in the README makes broken links in the Pypi description as well as logo not displayed (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/ewmh-m2m/1.1.0/))

I tried with a dedicated `pypi_description.rst` file, similar to `index.rst` Pypi and [GitHub](https://github.com/AlexisBRENON/ewmh_m2m/tree/b1e948b6dc123da4f89cf7d378e5ce1d78c9d117) do not render the RST if it contains `include` directive too.

Comment: This seems like at least two questions, but I can see that it is hard to figure out how best to divide them up. It seems like maybe you have already answered the questions "How can I compose part of my README.rst into Sphinx documentation?" and "Can a GitHub README.rst insert content from other files?". The question of "How can I compose the content of my PyPI project description?" may be answered through https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/ and its linked content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first attempt you describe is sufficient for GitHub and RTD, then the question is just how to achieve a valid long description source for PyPI, right?

In `setup.py`, you can set the `setup()` key word argument `long_description_content_type='text/x-rst'` and set `long_description` to a string of RST text ([no sphinx extensions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/)), so you can preprocess the long description source with arbitrary Python code earlier in the `setup.py`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am thinking about after [your comment] on my question. Currently, I use `setup.cfg` which limit capabilities. I will search for how to use both `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` and set `long_description` from `setup.py` after parsing/copying the README file.

Comment: I finally remove `long_description` from the `setup.cfg` file and preprocess my README in `setup.py` to build a valid long description. See [the code](https://github.com/AlexisBRENON/ewmh_m2m/blob/c70bb48fd102fc526112f4cfb7c33ae157d83037/setup.py#L41). Thanks.